# Вставка содержимого из JTextField в строку базы данных MySql

Tags: java, mysql

Возможно вопрос примитивный, тем не менее прошу помощи. Создаю телефонную книгу, в целях тренировки навыков работы с MySql. Суть вопроса в том, как можно из JTextField вставить строку в колонку базы данных?

```
String Sname = t1.getText();
String Ssurname = t2.getText();
String Number = t3.getText();
try {
    statement.execute("INSERT INTO telephone (Name, Surname, number) VALUES (Sname, Ssurname, Number)");
} catch (SQLException e1) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ошибка!");
}
```

Comment: Взять строку из `JTextField` и сделать `INSERT` в соответствующую таблицу MySQL. Если вы хотите себя потренировать, то почему бы вам не попытаться это сделать самому?

Comment: @LEQADA Я имел в виду когда через метод statement.execute() мы пишем запрос на размещения данных. Перед запросом я взял текст с полей методом getText, но синтаксис MySql отказывается принимать мои строки. 
Вот часть кода:    `String Sname = t1.getText();  String Ssurname = t2.getText();  String Number = t3.getText();  try {statement.execute("INSERT INTO telephone (Name, Surname, number) VALUES (Sname, Ssurname, Number)");}  catch (SQLException e1) {JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ошибка!"); }`

Comment: Чтобы исправить проблемы с формулировкой вопроса советую прочитать это:
[Как создать краткий, завершенный и достоверный пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Код, который является причиной вопроса, лучше вставить в текст вопроса (вы можете отредактировать свой вопрос), так же выведите куда-нибудь выбрасываемое исключение (`System.out.println( e1 );` хотя бы). Скорее всего, после этого вы поймете, в чем проблема.

Answer (score 1):

Ваш запрос полностью является строкой. Вы в неё не вставляете тех значений, которые подобрали из `getText()`.

```
statement.execute("INSERT INTO telephone (Name, Surname, number) VALUES (Sname, Ssurname, Number)");
```

в этой строке ни один из вставляемых элементов  не является переменной Java. Java распознает весь запрос, как строку. И выкинет соответствующий  `SQLException`.

По-хорошему, вы должны сгенерировать строку из полученных данных.

Что-то такое:

```
String querym = "INSERT INTO telephone (Name, Surname, number) VALUES (" + Sname + ", " + Ssurname + ", " + Number + ")";
```

И уже потом подсунуть в

```
statement.execute(querym);
```